# react-native app in android: battery being drained in background

Tags: android, react-native

I have an app built in React-Native that is draining a lot of battery on Android devices when in background. Need to significatively reduce battery usage by the app.

The app tracks location using react-native-background-geolocation (mauron85) but get location updates only every 20 minutes (10 fast interval).

A screen of the battery usage report (most time in background):

[image]

Maybe some dependency or wrong version?

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "d3-interpolate": "^1.1.5",
    "es6-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "firebase": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "lodash.range": "^3.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.19.2",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.48.2",
    "react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-checkbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.6.3",
    "react-native-fcm": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-firebase": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-google-places": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation": "^0.5.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native-navbar": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.9.38",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.25",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^5.4.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "0.0.70",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-persist": "^5.2.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Configuration of background-geolocation:

```
BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
    desiredAccuracy: 10,
    stationaryRadius: 50,
    distanceFilter: 50,
    startForeground: false,
    debug: false,
    startOnBoot: true,
    stopOnTerminate: false,
    locationProvider: BackgroundGeolocation.ACTIVITY_PROVIDER,
    interval: 1200000, //default 1200000 = 20 minutes
    fastestInterval: 600000, //DEFAULT 600000 = 10 MINUTES
    activitiesInterval: 1200000,  //default 1200000 = 20 minutes
    stopOnStillActivity: false
});
```

I appreciate any attempt to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my 2 cents. The screenshot says `Stay Awake : 7h 26m`. That seems to be the problem. It seems that you are somewhere acquiring a partial wake lock which is not being released. Check [Stuck Partial Wake Locks](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/wakelock.html) for resolution. It says and I quote:

> A partial wake lock becomes stuck if it is held for a long time while your app is running in the background (no part of your app is visible to the user). This condition drains the device's battery because it prevents the device from entering lower power states.

Comment: I was using react-native-push-notification, that requested the following permission: "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK". Trying another alternative to test if battery continues draining. So thank you! :)

Comment: Glad it helped Bruno. :)

Comment: Did removing it helped @BrunoConterato?

Comment: Sorry for late response! No, it didn't.. But I could now isolate the problem. It's occurring in "react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation". When disabling this module, problem goes away (no more stay awake). But still not solved yet, I really need a module that keep track of user location in background... I will try better configurations or another alternative for now. Again, thx for the support!

Comment: Any updates on this issue, we are also using same library and battery usage is high, we need to keep track of users location continuously